Modeling an HVAC system's energy
I'm trying to model the energy consumption on an HVAC system with intermittent stops.
As my model main parameters I use the following :

A temperature and RH sensor of ambient air

The HVAC working setpoint temperature.

AHU COP rating

the fans peak consumption in kw

The current motor Hz and also the estimated CFM

some specs of the system such as fans peak consumption in kw and the COP.


currently my model has 2 main components:
The first component is the Fan energy, using the peak consumption and a fan-laws based calculation using the cubed load percentage, (current motor Hz divided by the maximal Hz), multiplied by the peak performance in kw.
The second component is the thermal energy, using outdoor temperature and RH and knowing the setpoint temperature of the air after treatment. I assume the RH in the AHU is about 90% and the calculate the enthalpy difference (converting cfm to mass flow). then using the COP i convert the thermal energy to electrical energy.
finally, i sum the energy from the fan with the electric energy of the thermal treatment and this gives me the estimated kw for each time. with this i can also model intermittent stops in the system activity.
now first of all I'd be happy to hear your thoughts a=on the accuracy of this model. ill emphasize that i wat only the energy which is specific to the existing HVAC system I'm modeling.
Secondly, I'm looking on improving this model and making it more accurate. I saw a lot of energy simulators for building take into consideration also the heat absorbed by the space and emitted from the inside but  as it will require a lot more data i'm not sure if the accurecy improvment is worth it. any way i'd be happy to get any input.
** Another clarification regarding the specific system I'm modeling is that reheating of the air is not included in the energy calculation as it's a part of the tenant's energy consumption.

variable fan speed would be paired with variable compressor speeds.  I recommend you use design wet and dry bulb temp from ASHRAE (or wherever you live) standards.  90% RH may be appropriate for some parts of Saudi Arabia, hardly anywhere else.  Note also that COP is highly variable according to conditions.

As to my understanding the RH inside the AHU ideally is 100%, so i gave a value of 90% as a none ideal case. do you mean that by determining more accurately this non ideal number i can improve my model?

100% RH is fog.  The outlet of an AC unit is typically 55 degrees F, 100% RH which equals about 75 deg, 50% RH.  I think you should spend some time on how a psychrometric chart works.

I accidently sent before editing, couple of things:
regarding the wet bulb and dry bulb i didn't quite understood your intention, I'm measuring the dry-bulb temperature and the RH in the outdoor ambient air at real time are you suggestion measuring the dry and wet bulb instead? when you refer to design i guess you mean some general values suggested at ASHRAE literature i don't think it's better than a real time temp-rh measurement.

about the RH i don't quite understand how does 100% RH equals 50%?
your first sentence makes sense because the setpoint is usually indeed 55 degf in order to reach 100% RH and dehumidify the air. instead of 100% i suggested 90% for some robustness. the 50% RH and 75 degf indeed may occur after this process but at least in the specific system I'm modeling the re-heating part is part of the tenant's consumption so i don't consider it part of the HVAC energy consumption.

55 deg f 100% RH has the same moisture content as 75 degF 50% RH.

Yes but i was talking about RH, moisture content is a different thing, but because lets say a psychrometric chart can be represented as a 2d plain it's enough to know two quantities to determine the rest ( RH, dry-bulb,wet-bulb,moisture content, specific enthalpy etc. so in my case i chose dry-bulb and RH) I still don't understand your comment regarding the RH inside the AHU. would you care to elaborate why would it be different drastically then 90%? assuming a proper AHU which dehumidify the air and reduces the temperature below the dew point of course.

The load is based on the air entering the unit, not the air in the unit.

I think you can say more accurately that the load is based on the change in the air parameters from outside the unit to inside the unit.
Any way I'd be happy to discuss this on a different platform if you are willing to i entered my email in my profile description ,I'd be happy to chat.
